# UseState Data is not updating separately for each object

Tags: reactjs, array-map

I have made a shopping Cart App, where quantity of each individual items can be increased/Decreased on button click.

I have product data stored in Usestate in App.js file. I am trying to update quantity of each individual items seperately. But the problem is quantity of each items updates with the same value.

*Tha flow of quantity data goes upwards, from product.jsx>Card.jsx>App.js datasetter function.*

**App.JS code **

```
function App() {

const [data,setData]=useState([
  {
  id: 1,
  name: "Apple Juice",
  volume: 250,
  inStock: 20,
> quantity: 0,  I am trying to update this value individually.
  price: 2.99,
  image: 'https://media.naheed.pk/catalog/product/cache/ed9f5ebe2a117625f6cd6336daddd764/1/2/1219483-1.jpg',
  },
  {
  id: 2,
  name: "Grapes Juice",
  volume: 500,
  inStock: 10,
  quantity: 0,
  price: 3.19,
  image: 'https://media.naheed.pk/catalog/product/cache/49dcd5d85f0fa4d590e132d0368d8132/1/0/1033730-1.jpg',
  }
  ])

> Here is the setter function Which updates the data.

function datasetter(quantity){
    setData(()=>{
      const updateddata=data.map((data)=>({...data, quantity:quantity}))
    return updateddata;
    
    })
      }
    
     function consoledata(){
    console.log("apple quantity "+data[0].quantity)
    console.log("grape quantity "+data[1].quantity)
      }

  return (

    <div className="bodybg">
     <Card data={data} datasetter={datasetter}/>
     <button onClick={consoledata}>QuantityCheck</button>
                </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Card.jsx code**

```
function Card(props) {
  

>Quantity value passed to app.jsx function

function checkout(quantity){
 props.datasetter(quantity)

}


  return (
    <div> 
        <div className="container p-5">
    <div className="card mt-5">
      <div className="card-header bg-white d-flex">
        <h6 className="flex-grow-1"><b>Shopping Cart</b></h6>
        <a href='https://www.google.com/' className='text-danger text-end'>Remove</a></div>
        <div className="card-body">
{props.data.map(data=>( 
<Product data={data} key={data.id} productquantity={checkout}/>))
}
            </div>
            <div className='card-footer bg-white'>
              <div className="p-2 flex-row ">
              <div className='row h-25'><h6><b>Sub-Total</b></h6></div>
              <div className='row text-secondary'><p>2 Items</p></div>
              <div className='row text-secondary'><b>{"$6.18"}</b></div>
              <div className='row col-3'><button className='btn btn-primary rounded-5'>Checkout</button></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
  )
}


export default Card
```

**Product.JSX code **

```
function Product({data, productquantity}) {
    const [quantity,setQuantity]= useState(0)

>Quantity value passed to Card.jsx function

useEffect(()=>{
      productquantity(quantity);
    },[quantity])

    let stockChecker="";


if (data.inStock>0) stockChecker="bg-success"

else stockChecker="bg-danger"
   
> Functions for quantity increment/ decrement

    function increment(){
        setQuantity((quantity) => (quantity+1 ));
        

        // setQuantity((quantity)=>setQuantity(quantity+1))
        
        
    }

    function decrement(){
        if (quantity>0)
        setQuantity((quantity) => (quantity-1 ))
      
       
    }

  return (
    <div><div className="d-flex flex-row mb-3">
    <div className="col-2"><img src={data.image} alt="Product_Image" className="productimg"/>
    </div>
    <div className="p-2 flex-col flex-grow-1">
      <div className='row h-25'><h4><b>{data.name}</b></h4></div>
      <div className='row text-secondary h-25'><p>{data.volume} ml</p></div>
      <div className='row col-1 ms-1'><div className={`text-primary ${stockChecker} rounded-5 stockcheck`}></div></div>
      </div>
    <div className="p-2 my-4 mx-5">
      <button className='btn btn-secondary rounded-5 mx-3' onClick={increment}>+</button>
      <b>{quantity}</b>
      <button className='btn btn-secondary rounded-5 mx-3' onClick={decrement}>-</button>
    </div>
    <div className="p-2 flex-col">
      <div className='row'><h4><b>${data.price}</b></h4></div>
      <div className='row text-secondary'><a href='https://www.google.com/' className='text-primary'>Save for later</a></div>
      <div className='row text-secondary h-25'><a href='https://www.google.com/' className='text-danger text-end'>Remove</a></div>
      </div>

    </div>
    </div>
  )
}



export default Product
```

Quantity property from each object update with same values. If quantity of product 1 is 5, then 2nd product also updates to 5.

```
[
  {
  id: 1,
  name: "Apple Juice",
  volume: 250,
  inStock: 20,
 **quantity: 5**,
  price: 2.99,
  image: 'https://media.naheed.pk/catalog/product/cache/ed9f5ebe2a117625f6cd6336daddd764/1/2/1219483-1.jpg',
  },
  {
  id: 2,
  name: "Grapes Juice",
  volume: 500,
  inStock: 10,
 ** quantity: 5**,
  price: 3.19,
  image: 'https://media.naheed.pk/catalog/product/cache/49dcd5d85f0fa4d590e132d0368d8132/1/0/1033730-1.jpg',
  }
  ]
```

What I want is quantity to be updated seprately with different values.

Comment: You are missing the `id` when you set the data, thus it changes quantity of both objects to same one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to be able to update the data in the first object, modifying the setter function as follows does the job:

```
  function datasetter(quantity) {
    setData(()=>{
      const updateddata = [{...data[0], quantity}, ...data.slice(1)]
      return updateddata;
    })
  }
```

---

However, if you want to be able to modify any object in the array, you'll want to add a parameter to your function to specify, say, the index of the object to change. For instance:

```
  function datasetter(quantity, index) {
    setData(()=>{
      const updateddata = [...data]
      updateddata[index] = {...data[index], quantity}
      return updateddata;
    })
  }
```